# Exception when opening a Form using WPF's ShowDialog

Tags: .net, wpf, exception

I have a WPF application, when trying to open a form using `ShowDialog()`, I get this weird exception below on one machine.
Any idea what the problem might be?

> Exception Message = Operation aborted
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004
>   (E_ABORT)) Exception stack trace =
>   at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Native.Util.ConvertHresultToException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.FontCollection.FindFamilyName(String
>   familyName, UInt32& index)    at
>   MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.LookupFamily(String
>   familyName, FontStyle& fontStyle,
>   FontWeight& fontWeight, FontStretch&
>   fontStretch)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.LookupFontFamilyAndFace(CanonicalFontFamilyReference
>   canonicalFamilyReference, FontStyle&
>   style, FontWeight& weight,
>   FontStretch& stretch)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.FindFirstFontFamilyAndFace(FontStyle&
>   style, FontWeight& weight,
>   FontStretch& stretch)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Typeface.ConstructCachedTypeface()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Media.Typeface.get_CachedTypeface()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.TextFormatting.SimpleTextLine..ctor(FormatSettings
>   settings, Int32 cpFirst, Int32
>   paragraphWidth, ArrayList runs, Int32&
>   trailing, Int32& trailingSpaceWidth)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.TextFormatting.SimpleTextLine.Create(FormatSettings
>   settings, Int32 cpFirst, Int32
>   paragraphWidth)    at
>   MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.FormatLineInternal(TextSource
>   textSource, Int32 firstCharIndex,
>   Int32 lineLength, Double
>   paragraphWidth,
>   TextParagraphProperties
>   paragraphProperties, TextLineBreak
>   previousLineBreak, TextRunCache
>   textRunCache)    at
>   MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.FormatLine(TextSource
>   textSource, Int32 firstCharIndex,
>   Double paragraphWidth,
>   TextParagraphProperties
>   paragraphProperties, TextLineBreak
>   previousLineBreak, TextRunCache
>   textRunCache)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.TextBoxLine.Format(Int32
>   dcp, Double formatWidth, Double
>   paragraphWidth, LineProperties
>   lineProperties, TextRunCache
>   textRunCache, TextFormatter formatter)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.TextBoxView.FullMeasureTick(Double
>   constraintWidth, LineProperties
>   lineProperties)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.TextBoxView.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement
>   element, Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32
>   cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32
>   cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean
>   ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32
>   cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32
>   cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean
>   ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement
>   element, Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual
>   value)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual
>   value)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual() 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double
>   requestedTop, Double requestedLeft,
>   Double requestedWidth, Double
>   requestedHeight)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean
>   duringShow)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object
>   booleanBox)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.Show()    at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
>   at
>   Alberstein.UI.Views.MainView.menuWorkOnline_Click(Object
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    at
>   Alberstein.UI.Views.MainView.checkSyncstatus()
>   at Alberstein.UI.App.OnStartup(Object
>   sender, StartupEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object
>   unused)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) 
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args,
>   Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: That's a lovely stacktrace you've posted. Have you read it? In particular, the part of the stack that's looking for a font? `...at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.FontCollection.FindFamilyName(String familyName, UInt32& index)...`

Comment: @djacobson: That smells like an answer, do you want someone else to repost it as such for you or are going to do it yourself?

Answer (score 7):

I've experienced this same error, and the problem is with the Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache Service. Its cache file is somehow corrupted. By following the instructions in this MS KB article, 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937135, I was able to get the problem to go away.

This applies to both the 3.0.0.0 and 4.0.0.0 versions of the Cache.

Before I found that article, I had just stopped and disabled the service, and my WPF application started right up. I suspect disabling it will cause a slow down in displaying WPF applications (which is slow enough already), but after having several machines in the field have this issus, I disabled it and have had no problems since.

Comment: We had to disable the service.