# Visual Studio 2010 keeps crashing on startup even after it has been removed and reinstalled fully

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp-sp3

I have been struggling for days on this issue now and nothing seems to work.

I have had visual studio on my pc (windows xp pro) for 18 months and it has worked fine, but recently visual studio (2010) has started crashing before it fully opens up.

I have tried uninstalling vs2010 fully then reinstalling but it is just doing the same thing.

The error message recorded in event viewer is a devenv runtime .net error.

Here is the full error message.....

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32, IntPtr)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Native.Util.ConvertHresultToException(Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.FontCollection.FindFamilyName(System.String, UInt32     ByRef)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.LookupFamily(System.String,     System.Windows.FontStyle ByRef, System.Windows.FontWeight ByRef, System.Windows.FontStretch     ByRef)
   at     System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.LookupFontFamilyAndFace(MS.Internal.FontCache.CanonicalFontF    amilyReference, System.Windows.FontStyle ByRef, System.Windows.FontWeight ByRef,     System.Windows.FontStretch ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.FindFirstFontFamilyAndFace(System.Windows.FontStyle     ByRef, System.Windows.FontWeight ByRef, System.Windows.FontStretch ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Media.Typeface.ConstructCachedTypeface()
   at System.Windows.Media.Typeface.get_CachedTypeface()
   at     MS.Internal.TextFormatting.SimpleTextLine..ctor(MS.Internal.TextFormatting.FormatSettings,     Int32, Int32, System.Collections.ArrayList, Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
   at     MS.Internal.TextFormatting.SimpleTextLine.Create(MS.Internal.TextFormatting.FormatSettings,     Int32, Int32)
   at     MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.FormatLineInternal(System.Windows.Media.TextForm    atting.TextSource, Int32, Int32, Double,     System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextParagraphProperties,     System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextLineBreak,     System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextRunCache)
   at     MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.FormatLine(System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.T    extSource, Int32, Double, System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextParagraphProperties,     System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextLineBreak,     System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextRunCache)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(System.Windows.UIElement,         System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at         Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VisualTargetPresentationSource.set_RootVisual(Sys    tem.Windows.Media.Visual)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.WorkerThreadElementContainer.UIWorkerThreadStart(    System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,         System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,             System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
```

Comment: It looks like it is having a hard time finding a font. Does a repair do the same thing? Did you install SP1?

Comment: Check this article too: http://forum.i3d.net/threads/crashes-on-xp-32-bit.160438/ (which says to backup profile specific stuff and then recreate your windows profile. You might try this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022880/exception-when-opening-a-form-using-wpfs-showdialog

Comment: Mike thats what I thought, it is something to do with fonts.

Comment: Try creating a new user on your system, log in as that user and see if you still get the problem. That will rule out a corrupt profile.

Comment: Ok, logged in as another user and it works perfect. This is good news but I have lots of stuff set up that will be a headache transferring to the new profile. I have a gut feeling this issue is nothing big and am still hoping it can be fixed. Obviously if all else fails I will go to the new profile but if it can be fixed it would save me a lot of work.

Comment: Well I am a happy happy man! I just ran microsoft office idagnostics and it fixed 1 error, I havent got a clue what error but subsequently fired up VS and it worked! Im going to have a pleasant weekend now, thanks for all help.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not installed download and install [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

If service pack is already installed, remove SP and VS.NET, reboot and perform clean installation of VS.NET and then SP.

Update:

Visual Studio (devenv.exe) could be run with different options

```
/ResetSettings  Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to
                the specified VSSettings file.
/SafeMode       Launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows.
```

The /SafeMode switch will ensure you are launching the IDE without any additional addins. If the problem does not persist, chances are it's being caused by an extension. Use the extension manager and addin manager to enable/disable the extensions.

The /ResetSettings will restore default settings.

Run command propmt, navigate to VS.NET path and call devenv with one of the switches

```
CD C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

Comment: I have installed SP 1 and xp is running SP3

Comment: I'm afraid you need to test if uninstalling the SP will make any difference. Why do you set tags of asp.net and vb.net - does it crash on opening a particular project?

Comment: No it crashes every time, I set asp.net and vb.net because that is what I do and if I can have this problem other asp.net and vb.net develpers can too I guess.

Comment: Updated info regarding switches

Comment: I managed to fix this problem by running office 2003 diagnostics. Don't ask me exactly what it done cos I don't know. All I know is it has done the job. Thanks very much for all your contributions.

Comment: After all the steps mentioned in this answer I still had the crashing problem. Then I ran devenv.exe with the /SafeMode argument parameter then it loaded and reported that loading a package failed caused by an incomplete configuration (forgot to log name of package though). After restart it works normally, without any additional magic.